# Unable to add any tool to Model - drag and drop only adds the Default Geodatabase - ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, esri-geodatabase, drag-and-drop

I am probably missing something silly, but I cannot add any tool to the my newly created model (or to any old ones) in ArcMap 10.7.

If I try to drag and drop any tool, the default .gdb appears in the model - see pic - and I cannot seem to be able to add anything else but more version of the geodatabase.

[image: Model issue]

I set the .gdb that contains the toolbox and the relevant model as default, and ticked "store relative path names option in the model property and "current workspace" in model properties>environments.

I also noticed that drag and drop for older model produces the same issue (it only copies the current default geodatabase) and the only "workaround" is to copy the tools from other models and paste them in the model of interest to then edit them.

This is the first time I am creating a model from scratch and not just editing it, so I am not sure if and why it was working before.

**Steps to create a new model:** 
1.Open ExploreGasModel.mxd
2.Open catalog window and navigate to the relevant folder
3.Set FtCollins.gdb  as default
4.Right click default geodatabase and create new toolbox
5.Right click new toolbox and create new model
6.In new model>Model properties> Store relative path names ticked
and Model properties>Environments>Workspace> current workspace ticked
7.Save model
8.Open search bar and type buffer
9.Drag and drop buffer (analysis) tool, but instead FtCollins.gdb appears. Dragging different tools will create FtCollins.gdb(2), (3), etc.

**Steps on an already existing model:**

1.Open work_env.mxd
2.Edit an already existing model from Catalogue window.
3.In model>Model properties> Store relative path names ticked
and Model properties>Environments>Workspace> current workspace ticked
4.Drag and drop "make a new feature layer" in the existing model only adds "Default.gdb" to the model.

---

Adding the tools from ArcToolbox (and not the tools as from the search tab) works normally. Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you closed and restarted ArcMap?  If so, and if you are still getting this problem please describe each step you perform from starting ArcMap through creating a new model and beyond until you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Polygeo, Yes I have restarted ArcMap.

Comment: The Issue reoccurs if I right click and edit any model in any .mxd file. If I open the search bar and type the tool I need and then drag into the model, I still obtain the geodatabase and not the tools.

Comment: What happens if you create a new model?  You said you were creating a model from scratch. Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Can you drag tools into the model from the toolbox window, instead of from the search results window?

Answer (score 1):

Soft reset of user profile:

1. Close ArcMap and/ or any ArcGIS Desktop software/apps open on the
   machine in question.
2. Go to the following location in file explorer on the machine: `C:\Users\<your username here>\AppData\Roaming`
3. Rename the `ESRI` folder to `ESRI_old`
4. Close file explorer
5. Open ArcMap and perform the task

If the issue remains:

1. Restart the computer
2. Go to the following location in file explorer on the machine:
   `C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.x\Configuration\CATID`
3. Within each `Desktop10.x` folder that exists, open the folder named
   `Configuration` and rename the `CATID` folder within it e.g.
   `CATID_old`.
4. Close file explorer
5. Open ArcMap to blank
6. Open ArcMap and perform the task